# how can we remove the single key from multiple keys in a dictionary?

Tags: math, statistics, linear-algebra, tensor, factorization

I have the dataframe with 4 columns like row,cols,tube and rating.After converting to dictionary i am getting an extra element from column name as string.How can we remove the string from the dictionary.

nn = final_als_ho[['rows','tube', 'cols', 'rating']]
nn = nn.set_index(['rows', 'tube', 'cols']).stack(0).to_dict()

Answer (score 0):

if you are using python i have created a method to do just that

you need to create another dictionary2
then iterate over the first dictionary1
append values to the dictionary2 if it does not contain the specific value